# Qt context sensitivehelp

Tags: qt

I'm ready to start tackling the help system for an application that I'm building. I starting to look at the different classes that Qt provides and I have not been able to make that much progress as I'm stuck on the HTML document or documents.Do you create a document for each place that help will be provided? for example if I want help on a specific cell, it will be one document for that cell?
How do you assemble the hierarchy for all this documents, or the organization inside of it if is one document?

Comment: You could explain me better because I do not understand anything

Comment: This is from the QT Help Framework description entry: Building help files for the Qt help system assumes that the HTML documentation files already exist.

Comment: Even so, the title does not match your question, in addition to being broad and this means that it is off-topic in SO.